Enlarging suggestions font size on spellcheck on LibreOffice Writer
I want to make the Suggestions on spellcheck dialog larger because they are too small to see.
Thanks.

At one time, there was a scaling setting for screen fonts, which I no longer see. In that case, you might try changing the system screen scaling, or use adaptive technology to magnify an area.

@DrMoishePippik Thank you for the information.
